Angular 18 CORS issue with Springboot as backend
I am pretty new to angular 18, I am using springboot as my backend with springsecurity.
I am encountering CORS issue while using API request
When I'm using GET request to fetch data in ngOnInit, I am getting error but when I reload the page once, the error is gone.
For POST request. I'm getting this error:

export class ClassesComponent implements OnInit {
  classList$: Observable<any[]> | undefined; // Observable for async pipe
  isModalOpen = false;
  newClass = { classname: '', facultyname: '', description: '' };

  http = inject(HttpClient);
  classesService = inject(ClassserviceService);

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ngOnInit will run after the component is constructed
    console.log('ngOnInit working...');
    
    this.classList$ = this.classesService.getData(); // Return observable directly
   
  }

  // Method to open modal for creating a new class
  openCreateClassModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = true;
  }

  // Method to close the modal
  closeCreateClassModal() {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
    this.newClass = { classname: '', facultyname: '', description: '' }; // Reset form
  }

  // Method to create a new class
  createClass() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/classes', this.newClass, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        // Fetch the updated list of classes after creation
        this.classList$ = this.classesService.getData(); // Update classList$ with new data
        this.closeCreateClassModal(); // Close the modal after creation
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error creating class:', error);
      }
    });
  }
}


If you just want to proxy the api call in local development evnironment, please follow the steps below.
1. Create proxy file
Create a new file named proxy.conf.json in the root src folder of your Angular project. The content of the file should look like this:
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}

In this way, all the api calls start with /api will be proxyed to http://localhost:8080
2. Set the proxy file in file angular.json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "angular-16:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json", // <--- Add this line
      "browserTarget": "angular-16:build:development"
    }
  },

3. run ng serve
Note: Don't call backend api directly when using a proxy, call it with the front-end baseUrl or relative path.
this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/classes'); // OK
this.http.get('/api/classes'); // OK
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/classes'); Won't work!


Thanks it worked

@nithikeshbekkary if it works, please accept this answer, thanks.

The problem probably lies in the spring security config. Check that you have the config set to allow cross origin requests (CORS) from ‘http://localhost:8080’
Some details on different cors configurations in Spring could help based on your implementation.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
